# Synchronize - Apache web server session with Tomcat session

Tags: apache, session, tomcat, synchronization

I need to sync Apache web server session with Tomcat server session, to share authentication mechanism between 2 applications run on those two servers.

What is the way to do this? php code?

(I just need to authenticate the user who is going to use application runs on Apache through browser where who already logged in to the application which is running on Tomcat)

```
logging on to tomcat application cause 
  automatically logged in to apache application

log out from tomcat application cause
  automatically log out from apache application
```